# Vi editor, search and replace complex string

Tags: vi

I want to search and replace particular string in file.

Example, the string:

```
***BNS S&P/TSX60 ROC,SERIES
```

will become:

```
***BNS S&P/TSX60 ROC SERIES
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need exchange 'comma' (`,`) by 'space' (` `)?

Comment: It seems the reply will depend on your `vi` implementation and possibly mode. Can you state what `vi` version you are using and on what OS ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below command to replace the text,

`:%s/old-text/new-text/g`

`:%s/BNS S&P\/TSX60 ROC,SERIES/S&P\/TSX60 ROC SERIES/g`

Please note, slashes must be escaped with backslashes.

Comment: You can use a different character to avoid escaping the slash: `:%s@***BNS S&P/TSX60 ROC,SERIES@***BNS S&P/TSX60 ROC SERIES@g`